# Convert real to Integer in loop in Pascal

Tags: for-loop, pascal

I'm new in Pascal and I don't know how a fix this error:
Incompatible types: got "S80REAL" expected "LONGINT"

My code is:

```
Var
number1:Integer;
a,b:Integer;
a,i:Integer;

procedure number(number1: Integer);
begin
a:=1;
b:=number1+(number1-1);
  for a:=1 to number1 do
  begin
    for i:=1 to ((b-a)/2) do
    begin
    write('#');
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Error is here:  `for i:=1 to ((b-a)/2) do`

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the '/' ( (b-a)/2  ) with 'div'

'/' is real division in Pascal, 'div' is integer division

```
procedure number(number1: Integer);
begin
 a:=1;
 b:=number1 + number1 - 1;
 for a:=1 to number1 do
  begin
   for i:=1 to ((b-a) div 2) do
    begin
     write('#');
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: +1 And have a look at trunc/round if you want more control about rounding.

Comment: @NejcGalof: Please 'accept' my answer if you found it useful.